# How to fix "dpkg: error processing package systemd (--configure):

Tags: 18.04, upgrade, systemd

I recently upgraded from 16.04 to 18.04, and I think something went wrong with the upgrade. When I run `sudo apt-get install -f`, it tries to upgrade `udev`, but then I get repeated messages about "unsafe symlinks" and this error message:

```
dpkg: error processing package systemd (--configure):
 installed systemd package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 systemd
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I was getting a similar message about `systemd-shim` earlier, but managed to fix it. I also had a problem with incorrect `/etc/apt/sources.list`, but I think that's fixed as well. 
I was getting various error messages during the upgrade process, and at the end I had to "destroy" something instead of finishing the upgrade properly (unfortunately I don't remember exactly what happened.)
Any ideas as to what's going on?

Comment: Does this help you: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1171668/errors-were-encountered-while-processing-systemd-e-sub-process-usr-bin-dpkg-r

Comment: Yes, I believe so! Thanks!

Comment: I wrote up an answer based on the post linked above. Please mark it as correct if it helped you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check if you are the owner of all directories:

```
stat / /dev /var
```

If you aren't the owner, run the following in terminal:

```
chown root DirectoryYouAreNotOwner
```

Note: replace DirectoryYouAreNotOwner with the directory that you aren't owner of. So for example if the owner of `/` was `unknown`:

```
chown root /
```

Credit  to [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1215142/1060824) Ask Ubuntu post.

Comment: I also have the same problem. But this method does not solve my problem.

Comment: @ShahadMahmud Are there any error messages? Can you give me more details? What version of Ubuntu, computer hardware, amount of RAM, etc?

Comment: thank you !!!!!!!    I've upgraded debian 10->11  as sudo my_name and indeed the / directory was owned by me not the root.   ---